# SRAM Red 22 crankset & 10 speed cassette

Tags: sram, shifting

I have a 2010 SRAM Red 10 speed groupset on my bike, and I have just changed the front crankset to the latest SRAM Red 22 compact; I will also add a new KMC KMC X10SL chain.

The Front derailleur no longer shifts the chain off the large and small properly so I have also ordered a SRAM Red 22 YAW front derailleur to fix this problem.

My big question is this: will I now have issues with the rear PG1090 cassette? Should I buy a new 11 speed cassette, shifters, chain, and rear derailleur to bring everything up to snuff or will the front derailleur be the end of my problems?

Comment: I suspect somewhere closer to the former than the latter to be honest. Strictly speaking everything in the group should be 11-speed. In the past people have got away with interchanging, say, 9- and 10- speed parts, but with 11-speed the tolerances are smaller still.

Comment: You need a 11 speed chain if you have 11 speed components in your drive train, but likely if you want to go 11 speed everything should be 11 speed.

Comment: I did this on a Tern Eclipse which is 2x10. No problem. The Yaw is a phenomenally nice FD.